# If we have that $P(X = N_1+N_2, N_1=n, N_2=k)$, can we drop off the $N_1$ and $N_2$ so that $P(X = n+k)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable and $N_1$, $N_2$ are counts. If we have that $$P(X = N_1+N_2, N_1=n, N_2=k)$$ can we drop off the $N_1$ and $N_2$ so that $P(X = n+k)$? In other words, under what circumstances may be combine the variables into smaller terms?

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by "counts", but my impression is that no, you cannot do this. To my understanding, the two events $\{X=N_1+N_2, N_1=n,N_2=k\}$ and $\{X=n+k\}$ are not equivalent. For example $\{X=n+k\}$ even if $N_1=n-2, N_2=k+2$ say.

Comment: Indeed, $\{X = N_1+N_2, N_1=n, N_2=k\}=\{X = n+k, N_1=n, N_2=k\}$, but this is not $\{X=n+k\}$, in general.

Comment: A dumb counterexample to drive the point: $N_1,N_2$ being sayi.i.d.  Poisson r.v.'s with parameter $1$, and $X=N_1$. For any $k\neq 0$, the first probability will be zero, not the second.

Comment: I see, so formally, they are not equal because the set $\{\omega:X(\omega) = N_1(\omega)+N_2(\omega), N_1(\omega)=n, N_2(\omega) =k\} \neq \{\omega:X(\omega) =n+k\}$? In that intuitively, the set $\{\omega:X(\omega) =n+k\}$ has less constraints and hence the sample space is much larger?